# Datagrid refresh groups/sorting collectionview

Tags: wpf, datagrid, collectionview

I want to refresh my datagrid, but after refreshing, my sorting within the groups are not correct anymore...

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="SmsData" XPath="/response/conv/">
</XmlDataProvider>

<local:RowColorConverter x:Key="RowColorConverter" />

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SmsView"  Source="{StaticResource SmsData}" >
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="date" Direction="Descending" />
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="time" Direction="Descending" />

    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>

    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="recipient" />

    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

I call a button that refers to a method to do the refresh:

```
...

CollectionViewSource cvs = FindResource("SmsView") as  CollectionViewSource;
cvs.View.Refresh();

dataGrid1.Items.Refresh();


xdp = FindResource("SmsData") as XmlDataProvider;
xdp.Document = doc;
```

Comment: Why do you call both `cvs.View.Refresh();` and `dataGrid1.Items.Refresh();` ?

Comment: just trying :-) nothing works. Sorting does not apply after refresh